Why won't my scene play in the Video Sequence Editor?
I am having an issue in my attempt to view my current scene in the VSE. I have imported two mp3 files into the sequence editor as well. Every time I press play, the play head barely moves, and when it does, it is very choppy with no sound. I am assuming there is a severe lag happening somewhere.
I have also tried to mess around with the strip proxy and cache after chatgpt suggested the resolution and memory may be an issue causing the lag.
Here is a photo of what I see. Any help would be greatly appreciated.


If it's about lag (low computer resources for the scene), you can test it out by rendering the animation and watching the result.
